How long does blood stay bright red after being exposed to the air?
I am having a hard time finding the answer to this question. There should be a general time like x-minutes. Does it matter if it is in the sunlight? Maybe even an approximate time like between x-minutes and x-minutes.

Oxygenated haemoglobin is red, deoxygenated haemoglobin is purple (and there is no change in oxidation state when O2 binds to Hb). Oxidized haemoglobin is known as methaemoglobin and is brown in colour.  An example of an oxidising agent that can produce metHb from Hb is ferricyanide.  See 'points to looks for' in this article by Dixon published in Biochemical Education

In addition, blood will clot unless it is collected in the presence of an anti-coagulant such as heparin or EDTA.

I should have added that MetHb (brown) cannot bind oxygen.  In addition, it might be of interest to note that although the binding of O2 to haemoglobin is not an oxidation (we speak of the Hb molecule as being oxygenated), O2 bound to Hb contains no unpaired electrons and (unlike 'free' O2) is not paramagnetic.  To quote from a renowned paper by Pauling and Coryell: "The oxygen molecule undergoes a profound change in electronic structure on combination with hemoglobin"

Blood becomes bright red immediately after the haemoglobin molecules within absorb oxygen from the air, and in air it will maintain this color indefinitely as there is a constant supply of oxygen from the atmosphere and no way to lose it again.

Even when the blood clots?

blood does not stay the same color indefintely it changes as it clots and dries.

I was assuming perfect conditions, like a blood bank.

Geeze, I was not asking how it turns red or why it turns brown. How long does it take for blood to turn brown exposed to the air and assuming that the blood flow has stopped.
